# The lifetime of a WSN

Tags: voltage, sensor, electricity, supercapacitor, wireless-charging

What formula(s) should be used to determine the lifetime value of a wireless sensor node, charged up by a supercapacitor(its capacitance value its known), with a given power/energy consumption? It is also known that the capacitor has a known inital voltage. The WSN can operate at a certain minimum voltage.

Comment: Voltage is much higher in the example above, but the formula is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitance is 1F=1C/V (coulomb per volt).  Current is 1A=1C/S.  So your capacitance C divided by current I gives you S/V.  Multiply that by the difference between the initial voltage and the minimum voltage and that should give you your run time.

Answer (score 0):

Amp seconds over capacitance gives voltage. (Yes this is an ugly representation. But its easy beginner math)

But your devices have a minimum supply voltage before they stop working. So lets say they have a 1.8V minimum. And the capacitor is charged up to 3.3V.

This gives you 1.5 Amp seconds of charge you can use from the capacitor. Or ~417uAh. ((3.3V-1.8V)/1F) / 3600s.

Your devices supply current will change a little over supply voltage and you may need to compensate. But if your only drawing single digit micro amps. That means you have a large number of hours it can run.